# Usability issue with horizontal scroll bars and page scrolling

Tags: usability, scrollbars

Picture describing the problem can be seen below.

Issue : users can't scroll the page (vertically) properly as the mouse wheel is caught by the categories of items which do scroll horizontally

There will be another couple of categories below these so vertical scrolling is a must.

Been thinking about scrolling categories only when user clicks the control but clicking an item either opens a web page or a popup showing their content, so that won't work.

Do you know of an effective pattern to solve this usability issue ?

[image]

Comment: Just like to clarify, is mouse scrolling wheel the main issue because it scrolls both horizontally and vertically at the same time?

Comment: Example : when user scrolls on a white area of the page, it scrolls down. But as soon as mouse reaches a container with horizontal scrolling, it scrolls horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just **throw away the horisontal scroll**! Then you have some options:

1. Use **carousel-like scrolling controls**
   [image]
2. **Change layout** with one that has no scroll: some pictures and link "More pictures", or just wrap elements.
3. **Use tabs** for different content type.

Comment: Of course, if the user has a device which can scroll in both directions independently (trackpads, some mice), horizontal scrolling should still work.